# Continuously read from STDOUT and STDERR in real time

Tags: ruby

Say we have a small application (`example.rb`) which behave like the following ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

done = false

out =Thread.new do
    cnt = 0
    while !done
        STDOUT.puts "out #{cnt}"
        cnt += 1
        sleep 1
    end
end

err = Thread.new do
    cnt = 0
    while !done
        STDERR.puts "err #{cnt}"
        cnt += 1
        sleep 1
    end
end


while true
    i = STDIN.gets
    if i == "q\n"
        puts "Quiting"
        done = true
        break
    end
end

out.join
err.join

exit 42
```

It print something to stdout and to stderr, it must be quited by writing "q\n" to stdin, and when it exit a value is returned in the return code.

Now, I would like to write a small ruby script which can run this program in an external process, where stdout and stdin are captured, and when the external process should be terminated this is done by writing "q\n" to its stdin. This program is called `monitor.rb`.

This is what I have tried here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

class Monitor
    @cmd
    attr_accessor :return_code

    def initialize cmd
        @cmd = cmd
    end

    def run
        @runner_thread = Thread.new do
            Open3::popen3(@cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
                puts "#{Time.now} #{@cmd} is running as pid: #{thread.pid}"

                stdin.sync = true;
                stdout.sync = true;
                stderr.sync = true;
                @stdin = stdin

                t_out = Thread.new do
                    stdout.readlines do |l|
                        puts "#{Time.now} STDOUT> #{l}"
                    end
                end

                t_err = Thread.new do
                    stderr.readlines do |l|
                        puts "#{Time.now} STDERR> #{l}"
                    end
                end

                thread.join
                t_err.join
                t_out.join
                @return_code = thread.value
            end
        end
    end

    def quit
        puts "Quiting"
        @stdin.puts "q"
        @stdin.close
        @runner_thread.join
    end
end

mon = Monitor.new "./example.rb"
mon.run
sleep 5
mon.quit
puts "Return code: #{mon.return_code}"
```

Question 1: What is wrong with my code since the output of the external process is not being printed?

Question 2: Can this be done in a more elegant way, and what would that look like?

The code must be able to run on Linux and portability is not a priority, I uses ruby 2.0.

When run `example.rb` in a terminal I get:

```
$ ./example.rb 
out 0
err 0
out 1
err 1
out 2
err 2
q
Quiting
```

When I run the monitor application I get:

```
$ ./monitor.rb 
2013-11-19 14:39:20 +0100 ./example.rb is running as pid: 7228
Quiting
Return code: pid 7228 exit 42
```

I expected the `monitor.rb` to print the output from `example.rb`

Comment: You don't need the `do` on `while true`. Can you provide us with a little bit more information? What specifically is your output from each process?

Comment: Use the block form of `popen3`. It is more Ruby-like. Why is there `@cmd` immediately after the class opens?

Comment: instead of using threads, you can use `IO.select` to use the data when it's ready.

Comment: btw, there are some really nice e-books on these topics here: http://www.jstorimer.com/collections/ebooks

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're calling "readlines" which probably blocks until all input is received. In this case, you reach the end of your monitor script and *exit* it before those handles are closed, and since ruby hard exits when the main script exits, it just ends the script

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your t_out and t_err threads to use the following code. readlines will read the entire file at once and stdout and stderr will block until your script exits. I think this is why you were not getting any output.

```
while l = stdout.gets
  puts "#{Time.now} STDOUT> #{l}"
end
```

This should print out to the screen as soon as any output is available.